# rename files in Python: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have looked at the code here and it doesn't look that hard.

[Can't resolve WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155945/cant-resolve-windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

However, it doesn't work in my case. I quite new to Python here. I am renaming the folders instead of the files. Then each of these folders have some files that need to be renamed too.

Here is what I have so far in renaming the folders in a directory:

```
import os
from os import rename, listdir

path = r"E:\myFolder"
dirList = os.listdir(path)
print str(dirList)

for name in dirList:
    nameOrig = (name[0:(len(name)-12)])
    nameRename = nameOrig + "City"
    os.rename((os.path.join(path, nameOrig), os.path.join(path, nameRename))
```

Thanks very much

Comment: If the error message occurred without the print statement from line 6 I would suspect that you had no folder named E:\myFolder.
Did you?

Comment: Alternatively your rename is not using the actual name of the file so I would expect it to fail. Note that for a file named foo456789012345 the rename call would attempt to rename
E:\myFolder\foo to E:\myFolder\fooCity
On the last line shouldn't you use name and not nameOrig?

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure what the `(name[0:(len(name)-12)])` is doing... `name` should be the name of the directory itself to rename, which I would infer is `nameOrig`

2) `os.rename((os.path.join(path, nameOrig), os.path.join(path, nameRename))` has unbalanced parenthesis. Typo?

This works for renaming things in my directory if I remove one open paren from the beginning of the `rename` function call. and set `nameOrig = name`

*Note, I am using a Linux version of Python, which may or may not treat the results from the dir list differently

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. Jim was right, I need to use 'name' instead of 'nameOrig' in the last line. And thanks to Ryan J who caught the extra paren

The line that says

nameOrig = (name[0:(len(name)-12)])

is suppose to take out the last 12 characters out and replace it with a new name. In this case it is 'City'

So I had the folder names called

031_Indianapolis
032_Indianapolis
033_Indianapolis
034_Indianapolis
...and so on...

and I changed to 
031_City
032_City
033_City
034_City
....

Here is the final code:

import os
from os import rename, listdir

path = r"E:\myFolder"
dirList = os.listdir(path)
print str(dirList)

for name in dirList:
    nameOrig = (name[0:(len(name)-12)])
    nameRename = nameOrig + "City"
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, name), os.path.join(path, nameRename))

print "/n all processed"